# "I would have a car, which would ALLOW me to take myself from point A to point B faster"

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Is there such a sentence with "s" ("which `allows` me to ....")?

I'm talking about myself, it means I'm talking in first person (singular)

Comment: "I have a car, which *allows* me to take myself from point A to point B."  Am I not understanding what you're asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, "would have" is used for the subjunctive case, i.e. you are discussing a hypothetical situation.  "Which would allow" is an extension of the subjunctive situation being discussed:

> I have a bicycle.  If I could afford it, I would have a car, which would allow me to travel a lot faster.

The "which allows" construction is simple present tense, talking about an actual situation, so you need to eliminate the subjunctive from the entire discussion:

> I used to have a bicycle.  Now I have a car, which allows me to travel a lot faster.

Answer (score 2):

Either "which allows" or "which would allow" (if you use a modal such as 'would', then this is followed by an infinitive, but if you use a normal verb then the agreement is with "which", which is works as though it is third person [singular] in this case).

At the start of your sentence, I wonder if you mean "I'd like to have a car..."?

Comment: I meant something like "In case I would have a car ......"

Answer (score 1):

Placing *faster* at the end of this sentence is kind of obscure, I'd modify the sentence to:

> I would have a car, which would allow me to travel faster from point A to point B.

Other than that, I don't see any grammatical errors in the sentence.

Comment: great explain, thanks :) However I think Hellion answered better. But you're good enough, too :) Thank you. Better luck next time :)